# NopCommerce store inner pages is not getting when enable SSL

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, ssl

I have a project in Nop Commerce 3.0. Last week I try to enable the SSL encryption in my

website. I have enabled the SSL in my Store table then set

SecuritySettings.ForceSslForAllPages = false. Then after I test my application in local host.

**My home page is getting correctly**.

[image]

But when I click the **Login** link in my home page I get this error

[image]

**Code behind**

```
 [NopHttpsRequirement(SslRequirement.Yes)]
        public ActionResult Login(bool? checkoutAsGuest)
        {
            var model = new LoginModel();
            model.UsernamesEnabled = _customerSettings.UsernamesEnabled;
            model.CheckoutAsGuest = checkoutAsGuest.HasValue ? checkoutAsGuest.Value : false;
            model.DisplayCaptcha = _captchaSettings.Enabled && _captchaSettings.ShowOnLoginPage;
            return View(model);
        }
```

**In web.config**

```
 <authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms name="NOPCOMMERCE.AUTH" loginUrl="~/login" protection="All" timeout="43200" path="/" requireSSL="false" slidingExpiration="true" />
</authentication>
```

but this page available in http. I don't want this page with https

Please help.

**Edit** :

I have a excuse to say because i didn't know how to solve this problem. This project is my

new assignment. I am not a real developer of this project. this project is alredy works in

the live website without any problem. please see the screen shot below.( url is not

correct.)

**Live website home page**

[image]

**I clicked the login link it's correctly redirect the login page.**

[image]

I check my admin section for SSL configuration. But i am wondered it's true.

[image]

I connect my live database to the local host source code i get the above local host error.

I guess anything is depending the Nop.Core project for this SSL configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are use a reverse engineering tool for make source code from correct working Nop.Core dll from the website. we found some classes are use a helper functions for building URLs in the websites. This function is directly append the https string in the url.

These are the following classes and path in Nop.Core projects

1. ResolveLinksHelper.cs -- Nop.Core/Html
2. WebHelper.cs          -- Root
3. CommonHelper.cs       -- Root

We replace all "https" string to "http" in these functions.

Now the application is works perfectly after hosting.

Comment: Oh don't do that! Just disable SSL in the settings.... Also, you can just download the source. nopCommerce is open source

Comment: Thank you for your valuable replay. Dear sir it's our mistake because we get source code in last month all the configuration is same we do. there is no http in this above mentioned classes in our last code. I think there is a unexpected replacement occurred our source code in the development period.The reason to work this code in the IIS i found separate port mentioned in the Binding section.

Answer (score 3):

If you have enabled SSL, all actions annotated with `NopHttpsRequirement` will redirect to https. The setting `SecuritySettings.ForceSslForAllPages` just enforces that ALL pages (even those not annotated) should redirect to SSL.

The problem is that you are trying to run http and https on the same port. They need to be listening on different ports (you are requesting both on 9999)

Comment: I found in our IIS server binding  section there is a separate port number for http and https.

Comment: @RageshPuthiyedath That is expected. But when you explicitly select port using :9999 it will try http and https on both. However, if you do not specify port it will select the default port. 443 for https and 80 for http